# Pegar Id de tabela gerada pelo setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Boa tarde amigos, estou tentando gerar um link enviando um parâmetro que seria o ID da linha da tabela clicada

```
<a href="page?id=echo'.rows['id'].'">Editar</a>
```

esse código funciona no mysqli e mymsql sem problemas, mas no PDO não consigo achar um modo de "isolar" os valores do foreach pois eles são representados pelo v$. Segue o código (Copiei do w3shool > PHP > Database > Select)

```
<body>

<?php
include_once("../conn.php");

echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
echo "<tr><th>Id</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Partido</th></tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
function __construct($it) { 
    parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
}

function current() {
    return "<td style='width:auto;border:1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
}

function beginChildren() { 
    echo "<tr>"; 
} 

function endChildren() { 

    echo "<td style='border: 1px solid red;'><a href='senadoresTeste.php'>Editar</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>" . "\n";
} 
} 

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT perId, perName,perPP FROM elected"); 
$stmt->execute();

// set the resulting array to associative
$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
    echo $v;
}
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>
```

A questão é se é possível dar um "get" no Id ou qualquer uma das colunas separadamente uma vez que o foreach ta "acoplando" todas as colunas na variável $v. (ps: sou novato em php e pdo, não sei se esse é o código padrão pra select pois copiei do site citado). Obrigado a todos.

Editado ---
Aqui a outra página que estou fazendo o mesmo mas SEM O PDO, seria correto usar esse mesmo código na página com PDO???

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Partido</th></tr>";
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row["perId"]."</td><td>".$row["perName"]."</td><td> ".$row["perPP"]."</td><td><a href='teste.php?id=echo".$row["perId"]."'>Editar</a></td></tr>";
}
 echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: `$stmt->fetchAll()` já tem todos os dados todos (`perId, perName,perPP`) de `elected`. `$result` para que é que lá está?

Comment: Sinceramente não tenho a mínima ideia, eu copiei esse código do site w3school, ainda não trabalho com PDO então quis conhecer, existe outro modo mais "sensato" ou "comum" pra se exibir dados? Posso usar o padrão msqli por exemplo?

Comment: Editei a pergunta pra mostrar como estou usando em OUTRA PÁGINA mas sem o PDO